# Incrementing integer values, output unexpected

Tags: assembly, x86

I am working on an x86 ASM program where part of the output are numbers I have been incrementing at various stages. The output numbers are hardly what I expect... having trouble tracking down the error.

Initialized like:

```
SECTION .data
    ...
    numInc: db 0
    numDec: db 0
    numSum: db 0
```

Incremented like:

```
    inc     dword [numInc]
    inc     dword [numSum]
    push    stringOpt3
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4
```

Printed like:

```
    push    dword [numInc]
    push    dword [sum]
    push    dword [numDec]
    push    dword [sum]
    push    outputString
    call    printf
    add     esp,20
```

Where outputString is: (also in .data section, naturally)

```
    outputString: db `\nSet{1}: %5d/%d\nSet{2}: %5d/%d\n`,10,0
```

And the output is something like:

```
Set{1}: 134521233/514
Set{2}: 134521233/131584
```

So, I'm expecting results in the neighborhood of 0/3 1/3 ... ! Also, I expect the denominators to be the same considering the right==>left push pattern for printf.

I'm on Linux with an x86 processor using nasm to assemble and gcc to link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
numInc: db 0
numDec: db 0
numSum: db 0
```

to

```
numInc: dd 0
numDec: dd 0
numSum: dd 0
```

If you're going to increment them with:

```
inc     dword [numInc]
```

By changing **db** to **dd** you make **numInc** and friends take up four bytes instead of one. When you later **inc** or **push** the data as **dwords** (4 bytes) the size of the operations and the size of the data must match.

Otherwise, when you increment a **numInc** that only takes one byte as a **dword** you'd clobber the bytes following it if **numInc** is 255. When you push a one byte **numInc** as a **dword**, you were in fact pushing the three bytes that follows it as well.

When printing the result, the C code:

```
printf(outputString, numDec, sum, numInc, sum);
```

should be translated to:

```
push    dword [sum]
push    dword [numInc]
push    dword [sum]
push    dword [numDec]
push    outputString
call    printf
add     esp,20
```

I assume that's how you were expecting to get 0/3, 1/3 as output since the two "3" were from **sum**.

Comment: Thanks, already working better! Any thoughts on the print output "misordering"?

Comment: @d0rmLife, the ordering actually looks as expected to me. Push order: numInc, sum, numDec, sum the "sum"s map to the two "%5d"s in the format string.

Comment: Yes, I concur, but for some reason I had to reverse the order of the four pushes for the output to be as expected...!

Answer (score 1):

Some of your variables (e.g. `numInc`) are bytes (`db`), but you're using them as if they were dwords.

When you do something like `push    dword [numInc]`, what you're actually pushing is the value of `numInc` and the 3 bytes following it (`numDec`, `numSum`, and whatever else).

Either declare the variables as dwords, or perform byte operations on them.

Comment: How can I push only the variables contents? (For printing purposes via `printf`)

Comment: @d0rmLifem, you can "push only the variable contents" by making the variable take 4 bytes (change "db" to "dd") and pushing 4 bytes (push dword). i.e. the sizes of the data and the operations must match.

Comment: Either do as @d0rmLife said, or use something like `movzx eax,byte ptr [numInc]` / `push eax`